# Express email error handling, for nested middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express route for handling password resets, and with that i have a route, where i first find the user, and have some error handling with that, but now i want aditional error handling inside a nested function, and I'm not sure what pattern to use

```js
function triggerPasswordResetEmailSend(req, res, next) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    if (!email) return res.status(422).json({error: "Please provide an email."});
    UserRepositoryClass.findUserByEmail(email).then(user =>{
    if(!user) return res.status(422).json({message: "User not found"})
    sendPasswordReset(user);
    return res.status(200).json({user: user});
    }).catch(err =>{
        return res.status(500).json({error: err})
    }); 
  }
```

Inside this function i do some initial error handling. The issue now is that the sendPasswordReset function can also throw errors, but there are not caught by the `.catch()` function, so I'm looking for something to handle this function.

I have tried passing the `req and res` objects into the function, but that does not seem like a good solution. I could do some try catch or maybe return a promise. But i want to ensure, that i follow the same pattern and best practises as i have already tried to do.

Here is the code snippet from my mail function:

```js
module.exports = (user) => {
  const userResetToken = generatePasswordToken();
  UserRepositoryClass.setPasswordResetToken(user.id, userResetToken);
  const passwordResetUrl = PASSWORD_RESET_URL(user._id, userResetToken);
  return sendMail(options(user.email, passwordResetUrl));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **promise** instead of function.

```js
module.exports.sendPasswordReset = user = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const userResetToken = generatePasswordToken();

  UserRepositoryClass.setPasswordResetToken(user.id, userResetToken);

  const passwordResetUrl = PASSWORD_RESET_URL(user._id, userResetToken);

  sendMail(options(user.email, passwordResetUrl))
    .then(response => {
      resolve(response, null); // we can get result as (data,error) here error is null
    })
    .catch(err => {
      reject(null, err); // here response is null
    });
});
```

You can use sendPasswordReset Promise like this:

```js
sendPasswordReset(user).then((res, err) => {
  // here you can get your res as well as err

  if (err) throw new Error("Error while sending an email");

  console.log("response", res);
});
```